# Jquery: Conditional reference to attribute?

Tags: jquery, reference, conditional-statements, attributes

Is it possible to refer to an attribute of an element conditionally with Jquery?

What I'm after is something like:

```
$(".mylink":rel["2"]).show();
```

... which would "show the specific instance of .mylink element on the page that has rel="2" HTML attribute on it. There would be multiple instances of .mylink on the page, each with its own "rel" value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('.mylink[rel=2]').show();
```

If the "rel" value is a variable or something, you can do:

```
$('.mylink[rel=' + relValue + ']').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, let's the jquery execute fine but I it doesn't want to show.... It's just an integer, like in your first example.

Comment: Actually, looks like the show problem is caused by something else. Your code works, thanks.